# pass variable from excel to access

Tags: excel, ms-access, macros, vba

I have a VBA code in Excel that ask the user where an .xls file is a make something with that file.

What I'd like to do now is to pass the name of the file (`myFile`) to VBA code that I have in Access, in order to update a table with that file and other fields.

In VBA Excel, the name of the Sub is: `Sub UpdateSupplier(myFile As String)`

What is the code that I should use in VBA Access in order to use `myFile`?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data and code, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried in Access: vba create a new

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I havenot any idea of how to do that.. 
I've tried in Access:

Public Sub Update (myFile)
Dim Filename As String

Filename = Application.Run(UpdateSupplier, myFile)

of course, it doesn't return nothing.. I know how to call the subroutine UpdateSupplier (xl.Run "UpdateSupplier") but is not when I try to pass a variable.. any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Declare your variable myFile as public, that means not write:

Dim myFile in your Excel Sub, 

but write instead 

Public myFile in the Declare Section of the module. 

Then create a new Function in this module, which only gives back this 
public variable myFile:

function GiveMemyFile() as string

    GiveMemyFile = myFile

end function

Now you can call this function from Access to get the value of myFile.

Comment: Thanks libert. 
I guess I have to declare the public variable outside the Sub.. in Excel. After that, in my Access code, I call the GiveMemyFile as nFichero = GiveMemyFile (), but first I call the Excel macro with xl.Run "UpdateSupplier". However, I cannot run the Access macro because of Access shows a error message saying that "A Sub or Function hasn't been defined".. do you know why?

My Access code: 

Public Sub Supplier()

Dim nFichero As String
    xl.Run "ActualizarTelefonica"
    nFichero = GiveMemyFile()

Thanks

Comment: Alejandro: have you tried:   nFichero = xl.GiveMemyFile() ? because the function  GiveMemyFile() is in Excel and you want to call it from Access.

Comment: Thanks again Libert. Now, the issue is that a popup 438 error message says that "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method" pointing to below vba code in Access: nFichero = xl.GiveMemyFile()

Comment: Alejandro: when I read all your text from the start I understand the following:

Comment: You want to update a table in Access with a file name and other fields, doing this from Excel. Why don't you just open a database connection to that Access file from Excel and then just update the Access table ? If you don't know how to do that, I can post some code example.

Comment: Hi libert, my Access code import a table from Excel to Access using xl.Workbooks.Open (path), then run a macro within that Excel (xl.Run "Macro") and then update a table in Access with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Excel file name".

Comment: Hi libert, my Access code import a table from Excel to Access using xl.Workbooks.Open (path), then run a macro within that Excel by xl.Run "Macro" (at the same time that macro standardize another excel (plain text), and that is the name of the excel that I want to pass to Access)  and then update a table in Access with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Excel file name".
After that, using DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE etc" I update a table adding the date when the Access table was updated and the name of the plain text Excel.. sorry for the mess, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

think I found the solution now, it's so simple if you found it:

1. Your 'Makro' in Excel should look like this:

   ```
   function Test (ByRef strFilename)

      strFilename = yourFilename

   end function
   ```

The first 'trick' is, to use a ByRef Parameter 'strFilename' to give back your Filename.

2. Now in Access you can use:

   ```
   strNewFilename = ""
   xl.Run "Test", strNewFilename    
   Debug.Print strNewFilename
   ```

and you will see the filename the Excel Macro wrote in the variable.
I have tested this and it worked fine for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again libert. But I still cannot get the name of the file. It's empty when I try to pass to Access.  My code:
In Access:
Sub UpdateFile ()
Dim xl As Object
Dim strNewFilename As String
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\XXXX\File_stg.xlsm")
strNewFilename = ""
xl.Run "GiveMemyFile", strNewFilename
End sub

In Excel:
Function GiveMemyFile(ByRef strFilename As String, ByRef strPath As String) As String
///some code line that get the Excel file
strFilename = Dir(strPath)
End Function

Hope that help to find something wrong in my code. Thanks

Comment: Alejandro: in your code you say 'strNewFilename = "" xl.Run "GiveMemyFile", strNewFilename'

Comment: I am at the end with my understanding :( if you do after the run command debug.print strNewFilename there is nothing in it?

Comment: are you sure your Excel code really writes something into strNewFilename?

Comment: Hi libert, now is working! :)
I had two parameter, within GiveMemyFile function, the name file and the name path. So, I had to pass also the path. Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: oh, great! glad that I could help :)